# WPF, Отрисовка дочерних элементов за пределами ListBox (ScrollViewer)

Tags: c#, wpf

Кто-нибудь знает хитрый способ, как добиться того, чтобы дочерние элементы ListBox (или хотя бы ScrollViewer) могли вылазить за пределы родительского? Если родительской панелью сделать Grid, то элемент можно выдвигать за границы положив на Canvas и применяя сдвиги. С ListBox такая штука не проходит. Свойство Clip ListBox'а тоже попробовал - не получается.

Comment: У панели установить отрицательный `Padding`?

Comment: Отрицательный padding мне дизайнер забрил, а вот с margin получилось